# XCode Build task in Azure DevOps CI Pipelines

Tags: ios, azure, react-native, azure-devops

I am trying to build Using Xcode task of React Native Ios App. Earlier I was using Scheme and it was working fine but developers changed the approach and started using target where they are mentioning APP name (Apps are multiple and using same code base with slightly different UI).

I am not able to build my code with target and on google most of the blogs are only related to scheme. Help me to figure it out how can i run my application.

Right now I am using the below:-

```
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
  actions: 'build'
  scheme: 'MyApp'
  sdk: 'iphoneos'  
  configuration: 'Release'
  xcWorkspacePath: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/MyWorkspace.xcworkspace'
  xcodeVersion: '12'
```

Comment: looking at the documentation, you can specify the target with the `-target` param: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html

Comment: in azure devops, you would use `args` input to pass the additional param

Comment: -target requires .xcconfig file and that file is not available in the code. is there anything that i can refer to build it ?

Comment: In DevOps, Xcode task just calls xcode Command Line Tools to build your project. The same operations you can perform locally through the command line can also be performed using Xcode tasks. Likewise, if it cannot be implemented locally it cannot be implemented in the Xcode task. 1. ".xcconfig file is not available in the code"- Do you mean that there is no .xcconfig file in your project or that you don’t know how to refer to it in the Xcode task? 2. Please run `xcodebuild -list -project <your_project_name>.xcodeproj` to check if there are any build configurations.

Comment: 3. Are you able to build your project successfully with target using Xcode command line on your local machine? If you are, you can run the **same command** in a [CmdLine@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/cmd-line-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to use `target` in the Xcode and define the .xcconfig file.

Refer to this doc: [xcode task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/xcode-v4?view=azure-pipelines)

> xcWorkspacePath - Workspace or project path
> string. Default value: **/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace.

> Optional. Specifies a relative path from the root of the repository to the Xcode workspace or project. If you specify a value, you must also specify the scheme. Do not specify a value if you are specifying -target flag in Advanced Arguments. For example, MyApp/MyApp.xcworkspace or MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj.

If you need to use the `-target` in the Xcode task, you don't need to define the **xcWorkspacePath**.

To meet your requirement, you can add the `-target` and `-xcconfig` flag in the  `args` field.

For example:

```
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
  actions: 'build'
  sdk: 'iphoneos'  
  configuration: 'Release'
  xcodeVersion: '12'
  args: '-target <your_target_name> -xcconfig filepath/<your_configuration_file>.xcconfig'
  workingDirectory: 'Define the Working Directory'
```

If the xcconfig file is not in the repo, you can save it in the [secure file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) in **Azure Pipelines -> Library -> Secure file**

You can add the task `DownloadSecureFile@1` to download it and then use it in the Xcode task.

Comment: Could you share the xcconfig file for the reference.

Comment: @SudarshanSharma
 Refer to this repo to check the xcconfig file content: https://github.com/nishant-kumbhare/Swift-Examples/tree/main/NKEnviornments/NKEnviornments/NKEnviornments/Configurations  To generate the xcconfig file, you can refer to this blog: https://medium.com/@nishant.kumbhare4/working-with-the-xcode-configuration-xcconfig-file-75418d1554af